# Is Berlin safe for visit/work?

Tags: germany, work

I am thinking of finding a job in Europe and consequently moving there.
Social media draws a quite grim picture of immigrant/ISIS crisis in **Germany**, a country I first targeted as a place to stay.

Regarding aforementioned circumstances, I am worried about my wife's well-being during our stay.

My question is to german people, people living in **Berlin** on a permanent basis: do you feel safe in **Berlin**?

Thanks and sorry for bringing up somewhat delicate topic.

Comment: I don't think it gets much safer than Berlin.

Comment: No worries, no need to be too delicate: What you read on social media is just racist conspiracy-mongering. It's unfortunate that we often feel the need to mince words about these things.

Comment: I can't speak to an entire city, but I have my safety bar set very delicately: I don't always feel safe in Toronto, for example, and I never worried in Berlin including taking the subway alone. That was pre-ISIS but the whole point about terrorist attacks is that you don't expect them, so nobody can know if they are likely.

Comment: "I am worried about my wife's well-being during our stay". Not sure why you mention this explicitly. Are there any happenings which make you feel women face problems? Anyways as far as I am concerned Berlin is safe not just for women but for every body. Including dogs, cats and pets.

Comment: Don't let fearmongers ruin your life. The vast majority of visitors encounter no problems. This is the same thing that plagues a lot of visitors to the USA who worry about gun violence, despite the fact that gun violence targeting tourists is uncommon.

Comment: The biggest danger, as in any city outside a warzone, is traffic.

Comment: @RobertColumbia When I visit North America, I do worry somewhat about teenage driving and how easy it is to get a driving license there.

Comment: I did not downvote but I assume most of the downvotes are for lack of proper research and asking an opinion-based question, which is off-topic here. Also since you consider moving, Expats SE would be a better place for your question. Finally note that this is not a forum as your question implies for a little bit...

Comment: "Social media draws a quite grim picture of immigrant/ISIS crisis in Germany". That tells you much more about social media than it does about Berlin.

Comment: @Müller Because OP mentions worry about his wife, perhaps he's referring to the attacks on women that occurred this year at several festivals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, of course Berlin is safe.

There is [not a single European city in the list of most dangerous cities in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_murder_rate).  Germany overall [ranks 190](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_intentional_homicide_rate) in list of countries by homicide rate.

Most European cities are safe.  Some cities in Russia or Italy have high crime by European standards but none have high crime by North American standards.